# SSH access for hundreds of thousands of users

Tags: ssh, authentication, database, git, scale

I need to setup a solution similar to *GitHub*, where users can SSH to their git repository.

This should scale for hundreds of thousands of users, so my idea is to use a distributed filesystem for the data (so every node can access the entire data) and a replicated database to control the users (so again - every node can always access the entire list of users).

Using a normal **authorized_keys** file is impossible since users are not bound to a specific node, so I was looking for a way to read the list from a database (https://serverfault.com/a/443230/125948).

The problem with the **AuthorizedKeysCommand** command is that it only passes the username (which is my case - will be ***git*** for all users), so basically I would have to do a `SELECT pub_key FROM user` and always return the ENTIRE list for every connection.

This obviously is not the proper solution, so I was looking for another way to authenticate. Basically my question is: how on earth *GitHub* are doing that?

Comment: Since you're already setting up a distributed file system, what leads you to the conclusion that  _"using normal authorized_keys file is impossible"_?

Comment: Assuming there are a lot of users (let's say - millions) - it seems really slow to compare against each pub key when a user is trying to login, not to mention - to edit this file every time (remove keys for example). Am I wrong with this assumption? In addition, I don't want to hold 2 sets of users (db and keys) and try to sync them - I prefer to have it all in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the answer: https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast

They actually patched OpenSSH to perform a lookup against MySQL server: https://github.com/norbauer/openssh-for-git

Answer (score -2):

I think they have a tcp proxy sniffing the packet called [proxymachine](https://github.com/mojombo/proxymachine/blob/master/examples/git.rb)