# How do I prevent users from messing with their own .ssh folder?

Tags: permissions, ssh-keys

I'm administrating a RedHat server where users log in through SSH with private/pub key based authentication.

I'd like to prevent them from accidentally changing / deleting /chmoding the content of their *~/.ssh* folders. Some of them have already recursively 777-chmoded their whole own home folder because "it was easier to share files with colleagues this way" and shot themselves in the foot.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Preferably with standard Linux permission system.

Comment: Once they change their .ssh permissions, they aren't a user anymore, so no longer a problem :)

Comment: Also run a cron job every 15mins resetting the permission on their home dirs, they will soon learn

Comment: How about using SSSD and pull the keys out of LDAP instead of storing them locally?

Comment: This is not a technical problem and shouldn't be solved using technical measures. Human stupidity should be solved using administrative measures.

Comment: The root, ba-dum-tss, problem is that you are forcing people to use Linux who should not be using Linux.

Comment: @hardlib never do this. I bill a minimum of 2 hours a day if any automated tasks need to be undone. Until they learn. Do not mess with user space.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.

SSH is very picky about permissions and will not play with files it doesn't like the look of. Further, the users `ssh_config` is parsed *before* the system-wide config.

Having said that, it *may* be possible to put the files somewhere else and mount the directory as a read-only filesystem under `$HOME/.ssh` for each user. (It is possible - but I don't know how ssh and associated tools would treat this).

> Some of them have already recursively 777-chmoded their whole own home folder

Then you have much bigger SECURITY and training issues.

Comment: SSH will handle the setup you describe just fine AFAICT, provided that the permissions are correct on all of the files. If you were going to go to that level of trouble though, centralized configuration via `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is probably a better approach though.

Comment: I wondered about making `.ssh` owned by root, with the files in it also owned by root, so the user couldn't chmod them.  Unless they're competent enough to know that they can `cp .ssh .ssh_new` and move aside the old name, unless you set the sticky bit in their home dirs.  In which case insanity like `chmod 777 -R ~` is unlikely.)  Of course, then they couldn't change things *at all* in their `.ssh` directory, including not adding new host keys to `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Anyway, when you say ssh or sshd are picky, would they reject root-owned files?  Also, instead of a read-only (bind) mount, perhaps just `chattr +i` to make some files "immutable".  Or `+a` only allows append, which could perhaps work for `known_hosts` (but it doesn't prevent rename or changing permissions).  (Oh, there's another answer that mentions `chattr`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Last time I tried it, a root-owned authorized_keys was rejected if the user wasn't root.

Comment: @joshudson: Oh, so just `chattr +i` if you want to make things totally unmodifiable by the user.  Clueless users who think `chmod 777 -R ~` is a good idea aren't going to know how to undo that.

Comment: Anyone who does `chmod -R 777 ~` deserves to be locked out of the system for a while until their problem is fixed.  Maybe the pain will help them realize that's a bad thing to do.

Comment: @joshudson Root-owned `authorized_keys` worked fine for me, check out my answer, where I explain that option and more!

Answer (score 16):

It is hard to protect users from their own ignorance and incompetence.

But depending on how much you need to allow your users to manage themselves and how much you manage for them: you can configure sshd to look for keys in an alternative location outside their home directory and elsewhere than `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

### AuthorizedKeysCommand

A relatively complex solution is the [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand)  directive which rather than relying on authorized_keys files specifies a program to be used for lookup of the user's public keys in for example:

- a [LDAP directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap)
- a [database](https://serverfault.com/a/443230/37681)
- a (trivial) web service
- or when your usernames are identical to Github usernames, you can allow users to authenticate with the keypair(s) that they've uploaded there:

  ```
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/curl https://github.com/%u.keys
  ```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap); you'll need to created a suitable SELinux policy for the  AuthorizedKeysCommand  as that gets blocked by the default policies.

I love this approach as it can solve many issues surrounding the management of authorized keys: it adds centralised management, removes the chicken-and-egg problem of getting authorized keys to servers when you want to disable password auth in ssh and more.
It leverages the fact that public keys are not particularly sensitive (unlike their associated private keys) so centralising their management doesn't add risk IMHO and probably even improves your control and reporting capabilities.

### AuthorizedKeysFile

Slightly less complex is to store keys in a directory outside of their home directory.
For example   use `/etc/ssh/<username>` (replacing `<username>` with their actual username). This directory should have 755 permissions and be owned by the user. Move the `authorized_keys` file into it. The authorized_keys file should still have 644 permissions and be owned by the user.

In [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) adjust the [`AuthorizedKeysFile`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysFile) setting

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

And restart the ssh daemon

Comment: Love that github method

Comment: AFAIK that also works for on premise Gitlab and you’ll almost certainly have the same usernames there

Comment: For `/etc/ssh/...`, the key files can be owned root:root rather than being owned by the user, to further reduce the ability of the user to modify their keys.

Comment: While there's no risk to exposure of public keys there _is_ risk to injection. Allowing logins to anyone with access to an unrelated third party is a pretty big risk.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I can think of is to make `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` root-owned.

### Root-owned .ssh / authorized_keys

SSH is picky with permissions, but not unreasonably so. First, it requires that the user itself has read access to `authorized_keys` (which requires read access to all parent directories). Second, it denies access if any user other than the user itself or root has write access to `/home`, `.ssh`, or `authorized_keys`. This disallows `o+w`, and `g+w` for a group that has other users in it.

This setup works for me, the user can log in:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Sep 22 11:24 /
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 22 11:19 /home/
drwx------ 14 test test 4096 Sep 22 11:44 /home/test/
drwxr-x---  2 root test 4096 Sep 22 11:42 /home/test/.ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 root test   98 Sep 22 11:36 /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Since `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` are root-owned, the user cannot change permissions on them, or remove them. They also cannot edit their own `authorized_keys` file.

If you want to allow the user to edit their `authorized_keys`, you can add group-write permissions. This requires that the `test` group has no other members than `test` itself:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root test   99 Sep 22 12:04 /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

With either approach, the user can no longer create their own files under `.ssh`, so you may want to provide some extra files for them as well. Some that come to mind are: `known_hosts`, `config`, and `id_rsa{.pub,}` or other key types.

### Alternative: chattr

Some Linux filesystems supports *file attributes*, notably an *immutable flag*. Files/directories with the immutable flag set cannot be deleted, modified, or have their permissions changed. Only root can set/clear this flag.

This command would do the trick, even with the default ownership/permissions:

```
# chattr +i ~test/.ssh/{authorized_keys,}
```

Now `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` cannot be modified in any way, not even by root. If root needs to update these files, you'll need to `chattr -i` them first. Use `lsattr` to check for attributes.

This approach is simpler, but less flexible. It also needs filesystem support; I believe it's supported on at least ext2/3/4, XFS, and btrfs.

### Posix ACLs?

There's also [Posix ACLs](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists) (Access Control Lists), which allow a bit finer-grained control. I'm not too familiar with them, and I'm unsure if they are any help here.

### StrictModes

**Note:** highly discouraged, but provided for completeness.

The OpenSSH server [has a configuration directive](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) called `StrictModes`, which determines how picky SSH is with permissions:

> Specifies whether sshd should check file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting login. This is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their directory or files world-writable. The default is `yes`.

If you disable that option, you have more liberty in how to set up ownership and permissions. However, SSH is strict by default for good reasons. A user 777-chmodding their SSH files is a security risk.

Comment: "If you want to allow the user to edit their `authorized_keys`, …" – `sshd` from OpenSSH checks `authorized_keys` *and* `authorized_keys2`, so I think you can "hijack" one and allow the user to edit the other. I would "hijack" `authorized_keys2` because I expect tools like `ssh-copy-id` to append to `authorized_keys` by default and I wouldn't want to break them.

Comment: `authorized_keys2` has been deprecated for two decades now.  That it is still supported suggests that it may never be removed (as was announced years ago).  However, since sshd checks whatever files (with legitimate ownership and permissions) is specified in `sshd_config` at `AuthorizedKeysFile`, if you want an alternate filename or location, set it explicitly in config rather than depending on a feature added to support connecting not only with ssh 1.3 and 1.5 but also with the brand new protocol version 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Run a cron job to fix permissions each night.

Deleting files is a bit harder.  You could possibly restore missing files from backup from cron also.  But, it seems like you could get into weird edge cases with that... may need more intelligence than a script can provide.  I'd start small and add features cautiously to a restore function.

Comment: Perhaps have the cron job *detect* when users have set bad permissions, so you can teach them not to do it again for this or other directories.  Just silently changing permissions without alerting a human is maybe going to confuse the user or lead them to find some nasty workaround that's worse than we can imagine.